# How do I set my own color behind the dialog fragment on Android?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am working on an Android app where I am using `DialogFragment`. I want to set my own color behind dialog fragment once it opens.

Right now it is showing like light black.

Please see this screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2qRi.png)

Comment: So, you want to change the translucent black color behind the dialog?

Comment: @Shaishav yup. Please help

Comment: It is perhaps easier to occupy the entire screen with your fragment layout, set it the color you want, then center another smallwer layout, with the Views you want in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself. But you can try it using styles. Set `android:windowIsFloating` to false and `android:windowBackground` to my custom color in the dialog style:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/orange_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**MyDialogFragment**

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.MyDialog);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did it change anything at all?

Comment: yes, it only set the background of dialog not the one which is translucent

Comment: Okay, I figured. For the sake of trial and error, I've added a few more item in style. Can you verify if it helps?

Comment: @anjaliarora what do you want to change the color to anyway. Just in case we can find a different approach.

Comment: @anjaliarora You can use a regular fragment in that case. Just set a transparent background as you need with your dialog layout. You can even have transition animations similar to dialog. However, as a UX engineer too. I would suggest against it as users on a certain platform are more used to platform default behaviors. And, small things like changing the transluency of dialog bg may be off-putting at times.

Comment: Is it possible which I am looking ?

Comment: Of course its possible. Just set the background appropriately in layout of your regular fragment and in fragment transaction (for showing it) make sure you use `add` instead of `replace`. This, I've tested so I know it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'haven't tried yet, but you could try something like this:

```
    dialogFragment.getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(<your color>));
```

Comment: it set the background of dialog fragment but not the one which is tranlucent